# Can I automate with webdriver an iOS web application from Windows PC?

Tags: iphone, selenium, webdriver

I have seen on http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver that to use selenium webdriver tests on a real device for UIWeb, you need the iphone SDK and a provisioning profile. I want to write my selenium webdriver tests for iphone in Java (Eclipse).

Can i run test cases for ios as from a windows machine?Mac machine is compulsory to run tests? indeed, testers who design tests are used to on Windows and have no knowledge on Mac. Thank you

May I also ask if one can use webdriver to automate native, hybrid ios mobile app?

Once Iphone SDK is checked out from repo, may I run tests with any browser, like safari, firefox, chrome...?

Please help me

Comment: To run them in the simulator you will need a Mac. The iOS simulator only runs on a Mac. You can, however, create the tests in whatever language you like.

Comment: I am on a actual device and not emulator. Is code to run tests on iOS Device can be launched from a Windows PC?

Comment: I know the simple way to run webdriver code is to do that as from Mac OS. But, could be it possible to run directly from Windows? indeed, testers who design tests are used to on Windows and have no knowledge on Mac. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Only solution is Virtual Machine + Hackintosh but is not legal.

1. Download [this](http://thepiratebay.sx/torrent/8288683/OS_X_Mountain_Lion_10.8.3_VMware_Image_w__AMD_Support)
2. Read guide and install it, if your machine is Intel feel lucky,
   there are a lot of issues with AMD
3. Run VM with MacOS and download on it xCode and install it
4. Get trunk project from [checkout from here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout)
5. Build trunk in xcode
6. Now it will open emulated Iphone or Ipad (from what you choosed)
7. Go to emulated iphone and get IP
8. Run WebDriver app from emulate Iphone
9. Now run test like that `WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("yourip/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.iphone());`

P.S. I don't remeber all points correctly so good luck

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As in the step 7 and step 8, you suggest to go to emulated iphone to run WebDriver, I work with real devices iphone and not emulators. Does procedure you are suggesting is also applicable for real devices? thank you.

Comment: To run it on your device, you will also need a provisioning profile (which requires a developer license). Read in https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver#On_the_device
I didn't have Apple product so i didn't try it. Good Luck.

P.S. Yes, you can run on real devices.